# Crontab - stop sending mail, special case ||

Tags: email, cron

I need to put into my crontab small command, which is checking, if lighttpd web server is running, for some reason it hangups sometimes. So I got there:

```
*      *       *       *       *       root    /bin/pgrep lighttpd || /usr/local/etc/rc.d/lighttpd restart >/dev/null 2>&1
```

problem is, this send me mail every minute, in the mail is number of PID of lighttpd, which is running. For other crontab job, redirection work, so I assume, when is there "||", it makes problem.

maybe there should be better to rewrite crontab job, so it uses exit status of pgrep, so I can avoid "||". I am using FreeBSD.

Thanks for any help, for now I disabled this job

Answer (score 3):

Redirect the output of `pgrep` to `/dev/null`. All you want is the exit status.

`/bin/pgrep lighttpd > /dev/null 2>&1 || /usr/local/etc/rc.d/lighttpd restart >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: thanks a lot, this seems it is working, and is quite logical. The problem is, I can test it only using crontab, in command prompt it writes "Ambiguous output redirect."

Comment: @2ge Your interactive shell is probably tcsh. Try running `sh` first before testing the command.